# NSFetchedResultsController with many NSSortDescriptor

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nssortdescriptor

in my app I am sorting an entity using only one NSSortDescriptor, but now I need to filter the data for 4 different attributes. This is the code for the current sorting, the result are all records from the entity sorted by the attribute 'displayOrder', but I need to filter the records by four other attributes(year,month,day,group), all of them integer32 except group which is string :

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
  if (fetchedResultsController) return fetchedResultsController;

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = 
               [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"FavoriteThing" 
                           inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

  NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = 
              [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"displayOrder" 
                                          ascending:YES];

  NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] 
                              initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];  
  [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

  NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = 
              [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                                  managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext
                                                    sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"ThingsCache"];
  aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
  [self setFetchedResultsController:aFetchedResultsController];

  [aFetchedResultsController release];
  [fetchRequest release];
  [sortDescriptor release];
  [sortDescriptors release];

  return fetchedResultsController;
}
```

---

I have tried adding a predicate:

```
NSNumber *yearSearched = 1965;
NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear = %@", yearSearched];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:yearPredicate];
```

But after running the app there is an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the line `NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear = %@", yearSearched];`

Where the attribute 'todoYear' is from type Integer32

Comment: What do you mean filter and what did you try?

Comment: Thank you for responding @Wain, what I mean is to filter the records that match some conditions (year=x, month=y, day=z, group = @"Azul")...

Comment: So you should be adding a predicate, not another sort descriptor.

Comment: OK, I have just downloaded the Apple NSPredicate Class Reference PDF file, I will try to find there a way to implement my needs. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Hi again, I have included following lines to check it: NSNumber *yearSearched = 1965; NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear = %@", yearSearched]; [fetchRequest setPredicate:yearPredicate];
  But after running the app there is an error EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the line NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear = %@", yearSearched]; [fetchRequest setPredicate:yearPredicate]; The attribute 'todoYear' is from type Integer32. Thank you @Wain

Comment: You should add exception details if you get exceptions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NSNumber` creation is wrong (you're just setting the pointer to an integer). It should be:

```
NSNumber *yearSearched = @1965;
NSPredicate *yearPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"todoYear = %@", yearSearched];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:yearPredicate];
```

Comment: Thank you again @Wain, updating the code with your last answer throws no exceptions, but the app continues showing all rows, not the expected rows, there is only one record that has the value 1965 in the attribute 'todoYear'...

Comment: Are you ever calling `performFetch:` on the FRC ?

Comment: You would usually call it before returning the new FRC (when you create it).

Comment: I have updated your answer with my full source code, so you can please check what is wrong there.

Comment: Ok, move the performFetch: to the accessor and remove the cache from the FRC (you must delete the cache if you change the fetch request).

Comment: Sorry @Wain, I am not an expert yet, would you mind explaining what to do?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43075/discussion-between-wain-and-mvasco)

Comment: Hi again, I have included following line  [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"ThingsCache"]; and after resetting the iOS simulator, the app works fine, the predicate is filtering the data and the table shows the expected data. But after running the app a second time, an exception is thrown. I will put the exception text on your answer.

Comment: Just remove the cache name.

Comment: do you think it is normal that the app is working fine on a real device and when I run it a second time on the iOS simulator it hangs throwing an exception???

Comment: It throws an exception when you have not destroyed the cache but you have changed the fetch request. You could do this on the device if you install and run the app and then change the code and run again...

Comment: Thank you @Wain, but what should I do to avoid this issue? I don't want to have an unstable app...

Comment: Don't use a cache if you're going to change the fetch request (this is what the docs say). Or delete the cache when the fetch request is changed.

Comment: Honestly I don't know exactly what the cache is for, I have updated the code for my app from a tutorial,and step by step I am developing the app adding new features and learning from people like you, but I have tried to delete the cache and the app crashes. Would you be so kind and update my code in a way the cache is no more needed?

Comment: I have set the cache name as nil, and the app doesn't crash anymore, thank you @Wain